# C# can't take Windows InstallDate (f.e CIM_OperatingSystem)

Tags: c#, date, wmi

I want to get Windows InstallDate from `CIM_OperatingSystem`. I've tried lots of variants but didn't succeed. I created DataTime massive but an error appeared. I succeeded once and the data was 11111111 or 01.01.0001. I would appreciate your help.

This is code:

```
DateTime WindowsInstallDate;

ManagementObjectSearcher windows = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM CIM_OperatingSystem");          

foreach (ManagementObject mo in windows.Get())
{
    WindowsInstallDate= DateTime.Parse(mo["InstallDate"].ToString());                          
}

label1.Text = WindowsInstallDate;
```

Thanks in advance. Waiting for your answer. I'm a beginner  :(

Comment: what will you get for querying `SELECT * FROM CIM_OperatingSystem` on "root\\CIMV2" ?

Comment: i get InstallDate and  want to take Windows Installation Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ManagementDateTimeConverter class in your code to convert WMI Dates to DateTime classes.

```
WindowsInstallDate = ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(mo["InstallDate"].ToString());
```

It's worth noting this WMI class is pulling this data from the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion` and the value for `InstallDate`.  On Windows 10, this value gives you the install date of the most recent feature upgrade.  There is a key called `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Source OS (Updated on <DATE>)` that has the original OS InstallDate value.

That key is variable as the `<DATE>` specified above is the date of the last upgrade.  You will need to get the key name and the convert the registry data from unix (epoch) time to DateTime format, something like this would work. Excuse the crudeness of some of the code, more error handling can be added as needed.  This is just a quick example.

```
//Open Registry Key, search for subkey that starts with "Source OS" then open that key to get InstallDate data
RegistryKey SetupKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\\Setup");
string SourceOSKeyName = SetupKey?.GetSubKeyNames().Where(x => x.StartsWith("Source OS")).FirstOrDefault();
        
//Initialize new DateTime object with January 1st 1970 as its date (the start of unix time)
DateTime InstallDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SourceOSKeyName))
{
    int InstallDateValue = (int)SetupKey.OpenSubKey(SourceOSKeyName)?.GetValue("InstallDate");
    InstallDate = InstallDate.AddSeconds(InstallDateValue);
}

//If the key is not found the datetime value will be Jan 1st 1970.
Console.WriteLine(InstallDate.ToString());
```

Comment: Sorry, when i use to take datatime WindowsInstallDate = ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(mo["InstallDate"].ToString());  it works , but , when i use to Ram date, Cpu date , GPU date, and use this code, i have error. System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference does not point to an instance of an object." . Do you know, how to solve trhis problem ?

Comment: I think i'm missing some context.  Where are you getting Ram Date, CPU Date, and GPU Date from?  the win32_operatingsystem class doesn't have these properties.  Class Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-operatingsystem

Comment: Sorry its my mistake. i cant take info about InstallDate for cpu - Win32_Processor , for RAM Win32_PhysicalMemory, HDD - Win32_DiskDrive and GPU - Win32_VideoController. But i take 01.01.0001 01.01 OR error :(

Comment: For those classes the InstallDate property is optional and in most cases that I've seen there is no value.  If the property doesn't exist, it returns null if you query it. Trying to perform a ToString() function on a null object will throw the NullReferenceException error. You can either use an if clause to only get date if the property is not null or use null conditional and coalescing to make a clearly invalid DateTime object like `DateTime WindowsInstallDate = System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(mo["InstallDate"]?.ToString() ?? "00010101000000.000000-300");`

Comment: Then you can handle the invalid date later.  The classes you mentioned all have the following in their description for InstallDate... The InstallDate property is datetime value indicating when the object was installed. A lack of a value does not indicate that the object is not installed

Comment: Thank you very much!